# After inputting all the necessary values, python refuses to execute the while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am writing a code for a class in which I have to create a code that approximates the root of a cubic function between an interval using bisection. I have written a code in which should preform that, however; after inputting values for the variables, it preforms the print command then breaks and stops just before the while command. The text cursor enters into a new line like I am supposed to input more info when it's supposed to be executing the while loop().

```
import sys
print('The function should be in the format: Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D.  ')
A = float(input(' What is the value of A? '))
B = float(input(' What is the value of B? '))
C = float(input(' What is the value of C? '))
D = float(input(' What is the value of D? '))
a = float(input(' What is the value of the smallest x-value of your interval? '))
b = float(input(' What is the value of the largest x-value of your interval? '))
g = a > b
interval = (b - a) / 2
tolerance = 10 ** -6
print(interval)

if g:
    print('b must be larger than a'), sys.exit()

while interval > tolerance:
    iteration = 0
    p = (a + b) / 2
    f0p = A * (p ** 3) + B * (p ** 2) + C * p + D
    if f0p == 0:
        print('The root of the function is', p)
    else:
        if p < 0 and a > 0:
            b = p
        if p < 0 and b > 0:
            a = p
        if p > 0 and a < 0:
            b = p
        if p > 0 and b < 0:
            a = p
        iteration += 1

print('The root is x=', p, ',calculated in', iteration, 'iterations.')
```

I have tried changing indentation, and I've looked everywhere as to why the while loop would refuse to execute and the text cursor would drop down to a new line as if it wanted more input.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't waiting for additional input. You never modify the interval value, so the while loop condition is always true, and the loop just continues.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop gets executed, it just never finishes

Comment: why does it never finish? It should terminate after the interval is less than the tolerance.